# Unable to resolve service for type 'AspNetCoreRateLimit.IProcessingStrategy' while attempting to activate 'AspNetCoreRateLimit.IpRateLimitMiddleware'

Tags: asp.net-web-api, version, nuget-package, rate-limiting, asp.net-core-5.0

I have used the package AspNetCoreRateLimit Version="4.0.1" and I get the following exception: Unable to resolve service for type 'AspNetCoreRateLimit.IProcessingStrategy' while attempting to activate 'AspNetCoreRateLimit.IpRateLimitMiddleware' but when I use the package AspNetCoreRateLimit Version="3.2.2" it works. Although Version="4.0.1" is the latest stable version I am not being able to use it. What sort of bugs can I expect later if I keep on using Version="3.2.2"?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

According to the author of AspNetCoreRateLimit, you have to add following line of code in Startup.cs

```
services.AddSingleton<IProcessingStrategy, AsyncKeyLockProcessingStrategy>();
```

It seems as they no longer have a default IProcessingStrategy registered. See here: https://github.com/stefanprodan/AspNetCoreRateLimit/issues/236#issuecomment-883311511

Answer (score 2):

In the new versions, some code is embedded in the method,

```
public static IServiceCollection AddInMemoryRateLimiting(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton<IIpPolicyStore, MemoryCacheIpPolicyStore>();
        services.AddSingleton<IClientPolicyStore, MemoryCacheClientPolicyStore>();
        services.AddSingleton<IRateLimitCounterStore, MemoryCacheRateLimitCounterStore>();
        services.AddSingleton<IProcessingStrategy, AsyncKeyLockProcessingStrategy>();
        return services;
    }
```

Therefore, it will be sufficient to add the following services;

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddOptions();
        services.AddMemoryCache();
        services.Configure<IpRateLimitOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("IpRateLimiting"));
        services.Configure<IpRateLimitPolicies>(Configuration.GetSection("IpRateLimitPolicies"));
        services.AddInMemoryRateLimiting();
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddSingleton<IRateLimitConfiguration, RateLimitConfiguration>();
    }
```

You can get information about changes and option differences from [here](https://github.com/stefanprodan/AspNetCoreRateLimit/wiki/IpRateLimitMiddleware#setup).